# Checking not equal too on params

Tags: php

So I have the following method that gets triggered using the below call:

`$im->o()->em('id', '1234');`

Here is my method:

```
public function em(string $k, string $v) {

    var_dump($k);

    // Check if id or email is provided as key
    if ($k != 'id' || $k != 'email') {
        echo '<pre>Please provide either an id or email key.</pre>';
        return;
    }
}
```

Why is it when I do `if ($k != 'id') {`, that works and triggers the error, but when I add an `||` or to check if the $key is either an `id` or `email` string, it doesn't work?

Comment: You need to use `&&`. You want it not to be email and not id, right?

Comment: Thanks @user3783243, that helps a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition is incorrect. It should be `&&` instead of `||`.

Better way to do it would be -

```
$valid_keys = array('id', 'email');
if(in_array($key, $valid_keys) === false) {
...
```

Comment: @user3783243 Yes, I was considering code maintainability and future code changes...